# Treemap with d3.v3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am  unable to get treemap for this json as depth,area,x,y is all set as zero.
The code is as follows,

```
    var entries= [ 
        { "name":"gg", "class":"A", "value":90 }, 
        { "name":"hh", "class":"B", "value":70 }, 
        { "name":"ii", "class":"A", "value":50 }, 
        { "name":"jj", "class":"C", "value":74 }, 
        { "name":"kk", "class":"B", "value":40 } ]

    var nest=d3.nest()
                .key(function(d){return d.class})
                .entries(entries);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(nest));

    var canvas=d3.select("#chartdisplay").append("svg")
                   .attr("width",200)
                   .attr("height",200);
     var root={};
   root.key="data";
   root.value=200;
   root.children=nest;
    var treemap=d3.layout.treemap()
                      .size([200,200])
                      .nodes(root);

    console.log("treemap"+treemap); //gives treemap[object Object][object Object],[object Object]

    var cells=canvas.selectAll(".cell")
                     .data(treemap)
                     .enter()
                     .append("g")
                     .attr("class","cell")

    cells.append("rect")
                .attr("x",function(d){
                    return d.x; })
                .attr("y",function(d){return d.y; })
                .attr("width",function(d){return d.dx;})
                .attr("height",function(d){return d.dy;})
```

I had to nest json to get hierarchial structure and the value of root which is fed to tree map is below

```
 {"key":"data","value":200,"children":[{"key":"A","values":[{"name":"gg","class":"A","value":90},{"name":"ii","class":"A","value":50}]},{"key":"B","values":[{"name":"hh","class":"B","value":70},{"name":"kk","class":"B","value":40}]},{"key":"C","values":[{"name":"jj","class":"C","value":74}]}]}
```

Result of each object is,
Object
area:0
depth:0
dx:0
dy:0
length:3
value:0
x:0
y:0
I couldn't proceed later on. Please favour.

Comment: Youre trying to set a `rect` with `y`, `x`, `width`, and `height` attributes yet you dont give it any of that data.

Comment: I have just started with D3. Could you please help me to rectify?

Comment: I would say take a d3 tutorial, try to learn some of the basics before jumping straight in at the deep end - https://www.google.ie/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=d3%20tutorials&oq=d3%20tutorials&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65l2j0l3.2250j0j7

Comment: I referred https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svT9RdyQlrw&index=19&list=PL6il2r9i3BqH9PmbOf5wA5E1wOG3FT22p

Comment: If you read the comments from the youtube video youll see he says - **So for future reference; the problem here was that the data lacked a "value" property. Be sure to include a numeric attribute called "value" for each data element.** - also look at the data when he logs it @ 2:40 - each object has `dx`, `dy`, and `value ` attributes. Finally why start at tutorial 19?

Comment: I indeed started right from the beginning. And i indeed noticed it at 2:40. console.log(treemap) in my code itself simply generate [object Object] as I mentioned in comment and that's the main reason why it isn't fed, is what i assume.

Comment: you should do `console.log("treemap", treemap)` because currently youre adding an array of objects to a string which is why that is logging as it is

Comment: That is my ultimate problem. whatever that passes to treemap results in [object Object] notation only, instead of one that was in video at 2:40. How can it be resolved?

Comment: Yes - you pass an array of objects to your graph same as in the video, the difference being that your array of objects has values of 0. You can see your array of objects if you change the `+` to a `,` in your console.log like I said above. Its up to you how you set the values in each object.